# Suhosin for Windows

Tags: php, suhosin

I was wondering if it is possible to install Suhosin for php without completely recompiling the php library. I've looked around a lot an all I was able to find are resources for Linux and other windows alternatives. I did stumble upon one resource for windows, but it requires re-compiling php with Suhosin enabled, is there a way to do this on an existing, compiled php library?

I tried `php -f suhosin-patch-5.3.9-0.9.10.patch` in the cmd which gives a console output but no actual file is compiled, so installing the extension is not possible at this point.

here is the windows resouce:
http://board.deioncube.in/showthread.php?tid=96

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-f` is a flag for the compiled interpreter that makes the interpreter execute the specified **php** source code. suhosin is a patch to the php interpreter, which is written in **C**.

Therefore, you must [download](http://php.net/downloads.php) the source code of the php interpreter, apply suhosin, and then [recompile](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild) php.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, It seems like a good bit of work. Are the advantages of using suhosin great enough to go through with this?

Comment: Well, if you're running Windows, you're most likely not running a high-security system anyways. As a beginner, you're also more likely to somehow shoot yourself in the foot (for example, forgetting to update). Finally, many parts of suhosin are being integrated into the mainline compiler, so I'd say no.